# Disable/Enable USB debugging on Android every time

Tags: usb, android

I use an app to see the screen of my phone on my computer and control it with keyboard and mouse. The app needs USB debugging to be enabled on the phone. I plug in my phone, enable usb debugging and run the app with no problem, but whenever I disconnect and reconnect the phone, I have to disable/re-enable USB debugging on the phone. Every time, it's pretty annoying and it shouldn't work that way. I've had this issue on 3 different phones, and iirc it started around Android 5.0 update.

Answer (score 0):

Can you give the app that you're using? The community won't be able to properly diagnose your problem as it may not be an Android issue.

On a separate note, when the "Allow USB debugging?" dialog appears on your device, below the RSA fingerprint should be a checkbox which says "Always allow from this computer." Checking this before continuing should prevent you from having to confirm each time, although I expect a different software issue here.

Comment: the app is Vysor. But I think is more phone OS related than particularly the app.

Comment: I do check to always allow from this computer, and when I disable and re enable usb debugging, it doesn't ask again since it does remember my computer. I get the feeling that what's failing is the usb debugging setting.